# How can I evenly divide space between two frames using the grid geometry manager in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, tkinter, grid-layout

I have a tkinter application I'm trying to create. I've deiced to use the grid geometry manger instead of pack. It has been working well so far, but I've come across a strange problem.

The basic layout I want in my application is to have a toolbar frame on the top side of the window, which will expand to fill the window horizontally, and take up 1/5 of the screen space in terms of height. Another frame will fill the reaming 4/5 screen space(again in terms of height), and will also fill the screen horizontally. Another third frame will be under the second, and I will use `frame.tkraise()` to switch between the two.

Here is a minimal example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Toolbar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, root, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root

        self.lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Toolbar')
        self.lbl.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, root, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root

        self.lbl = tk.Label(self, text='PageOne')
        self.lbl.pack()

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text='MainPage', command=lambda: self.root.show_frame(MainPage))
        self.btn.pack()


class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, root, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root

        self.lbl = tk.Label(self, text='MainPage')
        self.lbl.pack()

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text='PageOne', command=lambda: self.root.show_frame(PageOne))
        self.btn.pack()


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._setup_window()
        self.frames = {}

        container = tk.Frame(self, bg='yellow')
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=3)

        self.toolbar = Toolbar(container, self, bg='red')
        self.toolbar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='new')

        for page in (MainPage, PageOne):
            frame = page(container, self, bg='blue')
            self.frames[page] = frame
            frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def _setup_window(self):
        self.geometry('420x280')
        self.title('backup')

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

The code above displays the following frame:

[image]

The yellow frame is the window which holds the tool bar and two other frames. The red frame is the tool bar. And the blue frames are the two main windows, which can be toggled between using the "MainPage" and "PageOne" buttons respectively.

As you can probably tell, my problem is that the tool bar frame(the red part)is not fully expanding to fill the reaming yellow space. No matter how much space I allocate for the tool bar frame, it does not expand.

My understanding was that if I put the tool bar frame in the zeroth column, and the
two main windows in the first, and I did `container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` and `container.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=4)` that would meet my needs. I made this assumption based on this excerpt from [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid-config.html):

> To make a column or row stretchable, use this option and supply a value that  gives the relative weight of this column or row when distributing the extra  space. For example, if a widget `w` contains a grid layout, these lines will distribute three-fourths of the extra space to the first column and one-fourth  to the second column:
>
> ```
>    w.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
>    w.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
> ```
>
> If this option is not used, the column or row will not stretch.

Was I wrong to assume this? Is there something I'm missing? How can I make my tool bar frame expand to fill the extra space?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need the toolbar to be taller than it needs to be? By the way: the code you copied was designed so that only the "pages" go in the container. While you _can_ put the toolbar in the container, that's not how it was designed to work. The container is best used only as a container for the pages.

Comment: I don't understand what this means: _" fill the window horizontally, and take up 1/5 of the screen space in terms of width"_ -- did you mean _height_? How can it both fill the window horizontally and simultaneously take up 1/5 of the screen width?

Comment: @BryanOakley Oops, sorry. I meant **height**.

Comment: @BryanOakley _"why do you need the toolbar to be taller than it needs to be?"_ - I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that?

Comment: @BryanOakley Okay, thanks for clarification. I was wondering about that.

Comment: The toolbar will hold some buttons, I presume. The way the code is now, the toolbar frame will exactly fit whatever buttons are inside it. You seem to be asking how to make it taller. Why does it need to be taller? Let tkinter decide the right size for the toolbar.

Comment: My recommendation is to `pack` the toolbar at the top and don't worry about the height -- tkinter will make it just tall enough to hold all of its buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tell your toolbar to stick to the south side of the available space as well:

```
self.toolbar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
```